# How to get ggstructure to produce plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand how to use `ggstructure` in ggplot2. Using the documentation examples, I can successfully get the example code to work: `ggstructure(mtcars)`. However, I can not get ggstructure to produce any plot from my own data read in from file. For example:

My data looks like this:

```
colors,hue,saturation,vibrance
BLUE,10,2,100
RED,2,86,2
GREEN,45,23,11
```

My code looks like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("/path/to/data", head=TRUE, sep=",')
ggstructure(data)
```

When I try to plot with `ggstructure` I get

```
Error: Non-continuous variable supplied to scale_fill_gradient2.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA)) :
invalid factor level, NAs generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
invalid factor level, NAs generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

I also tried to change the data to continuous, but this produced the same problem. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it doesn't appear that `ggstructure` (which is just a wrapper for `ggpcp`) was really intended to be used with non-continuous data.

The parallel coordinates plot function `ggpcp` attempts to rescale and then melt the entire data set. This results in a single `y` variable, grouped by the "variables" in the original data set. If you have a mix of continuous/categorical variables, this means this will be coerced to a factor, and how you plot it suddenly isn't clear.

Short version is if you have a mix of continuous/categorical variables, you'll have to cook something up yourself, I think.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what confuses me is that the `mtcars` and `diamond` data sets can be plotted with `ggstructure`, but I can not seem to understand what about my dataset is any different from those examples?

Comment: to be clear, i am looked to create a plot with colors on the x-axis and hue, saturation, and vibrance on the y-axis. this should produce a  9x9 plot with the intensity of color denoting values.

Comment: try running `data(diamonds)` first then `ggstructure(diamonds)`. Works for me.

Comment: @dr.bunsen Curious. I can't reproduce that. I still get the error. I'm quite certain it shouldn't work with categorical data.

Comment: Could you include your sessionInfo? In that way we can check what version of R and the packages you are using.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra I am using R version 2.13.2 beta and the latest version of ggplot2

Comment: @joran can you get `ggstructure(mtcars)` to work? This also works for me. It seems to me it is also categorical data?

Comment: @dr.bunsen Type `str(mtcars)`; when I do all variables are numeric. With `diamonds` three are factors.